# How does the split function in combination with multiple variables work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split

I have the following lines of code in an app but I'm unable to understand how the `split` function works. I mean why are there two variables separated by a comma on left hand side of line no. 8 and what exactly is this for loop doing?

```
def execute_testcases
  file_names = []
  originalfile_filewithtime = []
  original_file_map = {}
  originalfile_filewithtime = params[:excelfile]
  puts originalfile_filewithtime

  for value in originalfile_filewithtime
    original_file, file_with_time = value.split(',') # THIS LINE
    original_file_map[file_with_time] = original_file
    file_names << file_with_time
  end

  # Some more code...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split) splits a string into an array. E.g.:

```
foo = 'bar,baz'
foo.split(',') # => ["bar", "baz"]
```

If you have two (or more) variables on the left of an equal sign and an array on the right, Ruby will assign the elements of the array to the variables. E.g.:

```
bar, baz = ['bar', 'baz']
puts bar # => "bar"
puts baz # => "baz"
```

The line you're asking about is a combination of these two concepts:

```
foo = 'bar,baz'
bar, baz = foo.split(',')
puts bar # => "bar"
puts baz # => "baz"
```

It seems the for loop is iterating over lines in an Excel file, but what it does exactly cannot be determined from the code you have posted here.

Answer (score 3):

The `split` function returns an array of terms.

You can instead store the returned terms in separate variables as in your case.

`original_file, file_with_time = value.split(',')` is another way of saying

```
split_values = value.split(',')
original_file = split_values[0]
file_with_time = split_values[1]
```